# Life cycle of the demon in The Wretched (2019)

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wretched

What is the life cycle of the demon in [The Wretched](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_wretched_2019)?

According to the film:

1. It gets inside a host and make the host look mostly as normal.
2. If the host is killed, then it gets out and find another host
3. It changes mind of people around the host and make them forget their children and take the children away to a nest in the forest.

Questions:

1. What is the purpose to take the children to the nest, is that a necessary move in its life cycle? For example, if the host is not human, then no children can be easily taken.
2. Did it reproduce in the film? Is there only one demon in the film?